# How to prevent TinyMCE from sanitising "&"

Tags: html, google-analytics, tinymce

I have a google analytics `img` tag that I want to insert into TinyMCE. The problem that I am having is that TinyMCE appears to sanitise the HTML.

The code I need to insert:

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid={analytics_account_id}&cid=555&aip=1&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&dp={path}&dt={title}">
```

The result that I get after I put it into TinyMCE:

```
<p><img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&amp;tid={analytics_account_id}&amp;cid=555&amp;aip=1&amp;t=event&amp;ec=email&amp;ea=open&amp;dp= 
{path}&amp;dt=%(AdID)s" alt="" /></p>
```

Notice that TinyMCE changes `&` to `&amp;` and `alt=""` gets added to the end. When that happens my webpage doesn't display anything at all.

How do I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersand, along with quote, apostrophe, less than and greater than are reserved characters in HTML as they denote start/end of markup (so ​& " ' < > are reserved). In this case ampersand is used to denote the start of an entity, eg: `&quot;`, `&nbsp;`, etc...

Since that's a requirement of the HTML spec, if it is not encoded it will become invalid HTML as it'll take everything after the & to the next ; and assume it's an entity.

There is no way around this in TinyMCE. The link will still open using the encoded form though as browsers will de-encode it when copying, opening, etc.